# Is this subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ a topological manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider the set $\mathcal{M}_{1} = \{ \ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\ | \ y = -1 \ \}$, this is a plane. Also consider the set $\mathcal{M}_{2} = \{ \ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\ | \ x=y=0 \ \}$, which is a line.

$\ $

My question: Is $\mathcal{M}_{1} \cup \mathcal{M}_{2}$ a topological submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

$\ $

I know that separately, $\mathcal{M}_{1}$ is a 2-D submanifold, and $\mathcal{M}_{2}$ is a 1-D submanifold. But since the dimensions of these manifolds are not the same, I am thinking that $\mathcal{M}_{1} \cup \mathcal{M}_{2}$ cannot be a proper manifold, since the dimension of a manifold should be the same everywhere....am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Depends on the definition in use. Some definitions require a manifold to be of pure dimension, others don't.

Comment: If the line had intersected the plane, then you would not have a manifold by any reasonably common definition, since the point of intersection would have too exotic neighbourhoods.